# Is there a way to identify when a facebook application runs through a fanpage page

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Lets assume I have created a facebook app.So all those who(Admin) have facebook fan pages can **add my app into their fan page and run my app through their fan page**.I need to identify when someone run my app through his fan page.
Just assume this is my index.php file

```
//index.php 
<?php      
    include_once "fbmain.php";//Here I do all facebook Authentication parts 
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="http://localhost/test/test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
    </form>
    </body>  
 </html>
```

When a user click the "Upload" button,'test.php' file is loaded.In 'test.php' file **I want to display the id of the fan page**,

```
//test.php
<?php      
    echo "Hello".$ID_OF_THE_FAN_PAGE;
?>
//output eg: Hello 228276387189141
```

Can anyone tell me is there a way to do this?(I am using **graph api** and **php** to develop this app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is running as a page tab, an encoded signed_request parameter is sent to your app, which includes details about the  page the app is installed on

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

There's an example of how to decode the request and obtain the relevant fields.

The 'page' field in the signed_request includes the page ID, whether the current user likes that page, and whether the current user is an admin of that page

Comment: Many thanks friend,It really works.Now I can access the page id through my app when it is loaded via a fan page.